# What is resistivity function of a 3-bar electric switch?

Tags: differential-equations, fitting, finite-element-method, complex, electromagnetics

I answered a question on Physics StackExchange - considered as homework - numerically. The question is: What is the resistance of three stacked identical blocks, the middle bar shifted by its half width to the right. Conjecture: The resistance of the reduced vertical overlapping  blocks, 1/2.

Since it's a nice opportunity to test `NDSolve`, I prepared a graphical short answer, showing that there is a current in the outer parts, too, yielding resistance of about 3/2.

The short answer with the potential and current given is not quite perfect, because it's unclear what `NDSolve` is assuming implicitly at the inner boundary, I am presenting the complete implementation with Neumann boundary conditions here.

```
SetOptions[Graphics, 
  {ImageSize -> 50, BaseStyle -> {Opacity[0.6], RGBColor[0.2, 0.6, 0.9, 0.6]}}];

region[shift_] := RegionUnion[
  Rectangle[{0, 2.5}, {10, 7.5}],Rectangle[{shift, -2.5}, {10 + shift, 2.5}], 
  Rectangle[{0, -7.5}, {10, -2.5}]];

RegionBoundary[region[5]]
(* Line[{{0., -7.5}, {10., -7.5}, {10., -2.5}, {15., -2.5}, {15., 2.5}, {10., 2.5}, 
        {10., 7.5}, {0., 7.5}, {0., 2.5}, {5.,2.5}, 
        {5., -2.5}, {0., -2.5}, {0., -7.5}}] *) 

Graphics[{region[5], Black, Opacity[1], Thickness[0.1],  RegionBoundary[region[5]]}]
```

[image: switch]

Now the implementation of the Laplace PDE with isolating Neumann boundary everywhere and Dirichlet potential at top and bottom

```
LaplaceSolution[ region_, voltage_ ] :=
  Module[{boundary = RegionBoundary[region], potential, current, resistivity},
   potential = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[ϕ[x, y], {x, y}] ==
                                NeumannValue[0, {x, y} ∈ boundary],
                    DirichletCondition[ ϕ[x, y] == voltage, y == 7.5],
                    DirichletCondition[ ϕ[x, y] == 0, y == -7.5]},
                        ϕ  , {x, y} ∈ region ];
       current = Function @@ {{x, y}, Grad[potential[x, y], {x, y}]};
       resistivity = 1/Mean[(current [#, -7][[2]] &) /@ 
                      RandomReal[{0.01, 9.99}, 10000 ]];
   { Potential -> potential, CurrentDensity -> current, Resistivity -> resistivity}]
```

The current integral is implemented as a random sample mean, because the density as a derivative of a spline is irregularly discontinuous, yielding complaint messages by Integrate.

```
lp = LaplaceSolution[ region[5], 15 ]

(* {Potential -> InterpolatingFunction[ ... ], 
    CurrentDensity -> Function[{x, y}, {InterpolatingFunction[... ][x, y], 
                                   InterpolatingFunction[ ... ][x, y]}], 
    Resistivity -> 1.559712162176465`}
```

Some graphics

```
show[shift_] := Module[{pot, cur,  res}, 
 {pot, cur, res} = {Potential, CurrentDensity, Resistivity} /. 
   LaplaceSolution[region[shift], 15]; 
 Show[{ContourPlot[pot[x, y], {x, y} ∈ region[shift], 
       Contours -> Range[0, 15, 0.2], 
       ColorFunction -> (CMYKColor @@ {{1, 1, 0, 0 } (1 - #) + {0, 1, 1, 0} #} &)], 
       VectorPlot[cur[x, y], {x, y} ∈ region[shift], 
         VectorScaling -> Automatic, VectorSizes -> Automatic, 
         VectorColorFunction -> (Green &)]},
         Epilog -> {Text["1/∫ \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(j\), \(y\)]\) 
                \[DifferentialD]x " -> PercentForm[ res], Scaled[{0.75, 0.85}]]}]
]

show[9]
```

[image]

Now lets try to find the resistivity function especially at the opening point $x=10$.

```
pts = Join[Range[0.1, 9.9, 0.2], Range[9.901, 9.9999, 0.01]];

table = ({10.0 - #, LaplaceSolution[ region[#], 15]} &) /@ pts
```

set $x=10$ as origin

```
restb = Reverse[({Part[#, 1], Part[#, 2, -1, -1]} &) /@ table];

ls = ListPlot[restb, Joined -> True]
```

[image: resistivity switch graph]

```
fit[x_] = Rationalize[Fit[ restb , {1, Sqrt[x^3], x, Sqrt[x], 1/Sqrt[x], 
                     1/x, 1/Sqrt[x^3], 1/x^2}, x], 1/1024]
```

$$-\frac{\sqrt{x^3}}{27}+\frac{1}{48 \sqrt{x^3}}+\frac{20 x}{33}-\frac{241 \sqrt{x}}{85}-\frac{45}{181 x}+\frac{73}{39 \sqrt{x}}+\frac{85}{19}$$

```
Show[{ListPlot[restb] , Plot[fit[x], {x, 0.01, 10}, 
        PlotRange -> {0, 12}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5], Thickness[0.02], Red}]}]
```

[image: Graph of fit of resistivity in Laurent series in sqrt x]

#### Question

The graph suggests a solution in the complex plane with a map $(x,y) \to \sqrt{x+i y}$. What may be the analytical Laurent series representing the resistivity function around the point of the opening vertex?

Comment: I find this sentence not clear : "Now lets try to find the resistivity function especially at the opening point x = 10". My interpetation : the "opening point" is not a point somewhere in the graphics . One should understand something like : "Now lets try to find the resistance between the very bottom and the very top of the stack when the shift increase up to the opening of the electrical contact.

Comment: The problem setting is unclear. It would be nice to present the equation you are trying to solve and the boundary conditions.

Comment: I think it would be good to replace the word "resistivity" by "resistance" in the title of the question (some details : resistance units are Ohms, resistivity as a material property are in OhmsXmeter, "resistivity" for a manufactured wire are in Ohms/meter, "resistivity" for a thin plate for a current in the tranverse direction are in (Ohms^2 X meter)^-1, "resistivity" for a thin plate in the other direction are in Ohms, but to avoid ambiguity with resistance, one say Ohms/Square)

Comment: I think the same from above. Resistivity is the reciprocal of conductivity. What I see in your equation is that you defined a conductivity of 1. So, the resistivity will be the reciprocal of that value. The resistance is a different thing.

Comment: Can you show us what is equal to 1/Integral(Jy, X) ? I guess 1 is 1 [A], when the shift is zero. So 1 [A]/Integral(Jy, X) is a ratio  depending on the shift...

Comment: @Rolan F, instead of using random numbers for the integral you could use NIntegrate, like 1/(NIntegrate[current[x, -7.5], {x, 0, 10}]/NIntegrate[1, {x, 0, 10}]). Why -7 and not -7.5?

Comment: Can you give  a link to the question on the physics forum?

Comment: @Bastian: A plot of the current density shows a collection if discontinous splines, so NIntegrate doesn't find a good, fast converging integral, because the integration algorithms try to model the graph by continously mended splines.  The total current is constant over  any curve left to right by theory. The surfaces at +-7.5  are critical regions, especially for derivatives, where discrete numerical approximations tend to become wild distributions.

Comment: @andre314 I use resistivity in a very broad physical sense. In the moment, when a light bulb filamenent burns by letting go its diameter to zero, the total current or its inverse at a constant voltage is the only sensible observable. The PDE and its parameter world are the same for any 2d-potential flow problem, eg a water lock or the wind between twoe nearby skycrapers.